# Spring IoC: What about serialization?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, inversion-of-control

I am just in the middle of the development of a new software component involving the Spring Framework. I like it but now i have a question regarding IoC and serialization.

Given i have  this class (Omitted imports and package declaration):

```
public class EMailNotificationEndpoint implements NotificationEndpoint {
    private List<String> notficationEmailAdresses = new ArrayList<String>();
    transient private MailSender mailSender;

    public EMailNotificationEndpoint(MailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    @Override
    public void notify(Notification notification) {
        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        simpleMailMessage.setTo(notficationEmailAdresses.toArray(new String[notficationEmailAdresses.size()]));
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject(notification.getType().toString());
        simpleMailMessage.setText(notification.getMessage());

        mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
    }
}
```

NotificationEndpoint extends Serializable to ensure all implementations are serializable. The point is that i cannot serialize the MailSender (Which is org.springframework.mail.MailSender BTW) and want it to be injected at deserialisation time. Now my question is quire obvious: Can i do that? And if the answer is yes: how?

I'm free to change the interface and the implementations, so there should be a way to such a thing, even if this means i have to refactor the relevant classes.

Any Idea or hint is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about making it transient.

All you need to do is restore it as needed, when deserializing.

You could implement the adequate `readObject` method, to do that initialisation:

```
     /**
      * Always treat de-serialization as a full-blown constructor, by
      * initializing or validating the final state of the de-serialized object.
      */
      private void readObject(ObjectInputStream aInputStream) 
          throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        //always perform the default de-serialization first
        aInputStream.defaultReadObject();
        //do your other stuff, like initialization
        this.mailSender = ...
      }
```

> Note: Here, the object itself has to get the `MailSender` implementation, which is not very *DI* (Dependency Injection).
>   Either you are ok with that, or you find another way (tipically another object is involved after deserialization, and sets the correct dependency).

---

In case you really like to do the Dependency Injection, I found a link for Spring and Entities, that might contains general knowledge applicable to this case:
http://chris-richardson.blog-city.com/migrating_to_spring_2_part_3__injecting_dependencies_into_en.htm

Comment: Your Note states exactly what my Question is about. I am looking for a way to do this in a DI way. Maybe Spring is supporting something for that?

Comment: @Malax I know Spring gives support for objects that are instanciated outside of Spring, but post-processed by Spring. I can't remember how to do it right now.

Comment: @KLE - it's the ... bit in your code sample that's the hard part.  How are you meant to obtain the `mailSender` within the object when it is ordinarily injected?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods that serialize/deserialize the state and the class of the `MailSender`, something like this:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException 
{
  try
  {
    out.defaultWriteObject();
    out.writeObject(mailSender.getClass().getName());

    for (Field field : mailSender.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) 
    {
      if (!(Modifier.isTransient(field.getModifiers()) || Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) || Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())))
      {  
        Object value = field.get(mailSender);
        if (value instanceof Serializable) 
        {
          out.writeObject(field.getName());
          out.writeObject(value);
        }
      }
    }  
  }
  catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
  {
    throw new IOException(e.getMessage(), e);
  }
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException 
{
  try 
  {
    in.defaultReadObject();     
    mailSender = (MailSender)Class.forName((String)in.readObject()).newInstance();

    Map<String, Field> fields = new HashMap<String, Field>();
    for (Field field : mailSender.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) 
    {
      fields.put(field.getName(), field);
    }  

    int remainingFields = mailSender.getClass().getDeclaredFields().length;  
    while (remainingFields > 0) 
    {   
      String fieldName = (String)in.readObject();
      Object value = in.readObject();
    fields.get(fieldName).set(mailSender, value);
      remainingFields--;
    }
  }
  catch (IllegalAccessException e)
  {
    throw new IOException(e.getMessage(), e);
  }
  catch (InstantiationException e)
  {
    throw new IOException(e.getMessage(), e);
  }
}
```

You'll probably want to tighten up the reflective code and maybe use recursion if the state you require isn't serializable but you the gist of what you need to do.